# IE 11 lose focus from text in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

Steps to reproduce:

- We have html page with iframe inside it, which contains some text + some text outside iframe.
- select the text inside iframe
- select the text outside iframe

Expected result: text in iframe remains selected (focused). This is how it works in Chrome and Firefox.

Actual result: text in iframe loose focus -> in IE 11

Here you can check it by yourself:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01ks50bw/)

```html
<div>
  Start test
  <iframe src="javascript:'&lt;p&gt;Hello world from iframe!&lt;/p&gt;'">

</iframe> End test
</div>
```

Is there any way to workaround this problem, using css styles or javascript?